# Убрать ajax запрос

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Всех приветствую! Есть такие строчки кода :

```
$.ajax({
  url:'insert.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: dannie,
  success: function (data) {
    if (data) {
      alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-right');
      alertify.success('Клиент успешно Отредактирован!'); 
      alertify.get('notifier','position'));
    } else {            
      alertify.alert("Ошибка");
    }
  }
})
```

Тут выполняемый ajax запрос ведёт на другой файл "insert.php" но мне это не надо, у меня этот запрос в этом же файле . Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Сохранить" данные обновлялись в бд и  при этом выводился алерт?
Вот полный код файла:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>редактирование клиента</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- include the script -->
    <script src="alertifyjs/alertify.min.js"></script>
    <!-- include the style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alertifyjs/css/alertify.min.css"/>
    <!-- include a theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alertifyjs/css/themes/default.min.css"/>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function () {
            $("form").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // !!!
                var dannie = $("form").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'update.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: dannie,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            alertify.set('notifier', 'position', 'top-right');
                            alertify.success('Клиент успешно Отредактирова!');
                        }
                        else {
                            alertify.alert("Ошибка");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
include_once("db1.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $klient = strip_tags(trim($_POST['klient']));
    $op_firma = strip_tags(trim($_POST['op_forma']));
    $naimen = strip_tags(trim($_POST['naimen']));
    $otrasl = strip_tags(trim($_POST['otrasl']));
    $telefon = strip_tags(trim($_POST['telefon']));
    $email = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']));
    $kont_lico = strip_tags(trim($_POST['kont_lico']));
    $dolznost = strip_tags(trim($_POST['dolznost']));
    mysql_query("
        UPDATE klienti SET klient='$klient', op_forma='$op_firma', naimen='$naimen',otrasl='$otrasl',telefon='$telefon',email='$email',kont_lico='$kont_lico',dolznost='$dolznost' WHERE id='$id' 
               ");
}
$rezult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klienti WHERE id='$id' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rezult);
mysql_close();
?>
<form method="post" action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" id="form">
    клиент<br/>
    <input type="text" name="klient" value="<?php echo $row['klient']; ?>"/> <br/>

    ОП_форма <br/>
    <input type="text" name="op_forma" value="<?php echo $row['op_forma']; ?>"/> <br/> <!-- cols="10" rows="10" -->

    Наимен <br/>
    <input type="text" name="naimen" value="<?php echo $row['naimen']; ?>"/><br/><br/>
    отрасль <br/>
    <input type="text" name="otrasl" value="<?php echo $row['otrasl']; ?>"/><br/><br/>
    telefon <br/>
    <input type="text" name="telefon" value="<?php echo $row['telefon']; ?>"/><br/><br/>
    email <br/>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>"/><br/><br/>
    ОП фирмы <br/>
    <input type="text" name="kont_lico" value="<?php echo $row['kont_lico']; ?>"/><br/><br/>
    ОП фирмы <br/>
    <input type="text" name="dolznost" value="<?php echo $row['dolznost']; ?>"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="time" value="<?php echo date('H:i:s'); ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Сохранить"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-right');
                  alertify.success('Клиент успешно Отредактирован!'); ` поставьте на событие нажатии кнопки(если нужно показывать пр нажатии на кнопку и не нужно отправлять форму) и собственно удалите `$ ("form").submit(function(event){ ... });` ...

Comment: Пытаюсь сделать вот так, но ничего не происходит `<input type="submit" name="save" value="Сохранить" onclick="alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-right'); alertify.success('Клиент успешно Отредактирован!' ");  />` Я отредактировал вопрос пару минут назад, как сделать чтобы данные по нажатию этой кнопки обновлялись в бд и выводился алерт?

Comment: Код читать невозможно. Поработайте над форматированием - это вам так же поможет проще разбираться в том, что вы уже написали. В качестве тим лида я бы не принял такой код - заставил переписывать. В качестве клиента - я бы за него не заплатил. В качестве студента я бы поржал над ним. А в качестве члена сообщества steckoverflow настоятельно рекомендую отформатировать код так, чтоб он стал читабельным.

Comment: @Razzwan Поработал над форматированием, можете пожалуйста помочь с проблемой?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $ ("form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-right');
    alertify.success('Клиент успешно Отредактирован!');
  });
});
```

Comment: Алерт есть, но не обновляет данные в бд

Comment: @roman вы просили убрать запрос? я убрал. Если нет запроса то что по вашему будет что либо обновлять в бд?

Comment: получается я не со всем точно описал проблему,  надо чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Сохранить" данные обновлялись  в бд при этом выводился алерт

Comment: @roman тогда я немного не допонимаю как именно вы хотите выполнить код на стороне клиента который должен что то сохранить в БД? БД же у вас находится не у клиента?

Comment: Если из первого моего сообщения убрать  всё ,что находится в тегах script, то происходит обновление бд после нажатия кнопки "Сохранить". Но мне надо,чтобы алерт отображался после нажатия кнопки "Сохранить" для этого я и добавил то,что находится в тегах script, но мне не надо чтобы Ajax брал запрос из файла insert.php как это указано т.к. этот запрос и так находится в  файле в котором я использую тег script.

Comment: @roman на сколько мне известно, пыха выполняется на сервере, js на клиенте, в вашем случае, это работает видимо потому что у вас локальный сервер.

Comment: @roman что-то подсказывает, что данные в форме у Вас обновляются после перезагрузки страницы, без перезагрузки страницы данные могут обновляться только через запрос js/jquery

Comment: тогда правильным будет поместить код php в отдельный файл и  к нему обращаться как сделано в тегах script?

Comment: @roman да, ведь вы в последствии, я надеюсь,  разместите ваш проект на удаленной машине.

Comment: @Vyacheslav Danshinа подскажите пожалуйста,как мне грамотно перенести данные в другой файл ,ведь просто скопировав php код, не работает